# PL/SQL : Encountered the symbol "END"

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, sqlplus

I get the following error, even though I have checked the code carefully. I don't know what I'm missing.

LINE/COL ERROR

---

31/1     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the
         following:

CODE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_ssjm_newworkorder
(   workorderno IN NUMBER,
company     IN CHAR,
attention   IN CHAR,
datedue     IN DATE,
loggedby    IN CHAR
)

AS  id     NUMBER;
today         DATE:=SYSDATE;
BEGIN
SELECT  client_id   --grab client_id
INTO id 
FROM    ssjm_client
WHERE ssjm_client.name=company;

IF id IS NULL THEN  --check if client exists by checking if client_id is there
    dbms_output.put_line('Please create client first');
    GOTO the_end;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO ssjm_workorder      VALUES(workorderno,workorderno,company,loggedby,attention,'Received',today,datedue,id);
END IF;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    raise_application_error(-20999,'An error occured in' ||
        SQLCODE || '-ERROR-' || SQLERRM);

<<the_end>>

END sp_ssjm_newworkorder;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several spots in your code needed attention:

1. The reason you've got that error is because label  `<<the_end>>` should be placed before the `EXCEPTION` section.
2. Operator is required after a label. So if you want to jump to the end of a stored procedure and no other actions required `NULL` operator should be used.

To that end your code should look like this:

```
IF id IS NULL THEN  --check if client exists by checking if client_id is there
    dbms_output.put_line('Please create client first');
    GOTO the_end;
ELSE
    INSERT INTO ssjm_workorder
 VALUES(workorderno,workorderno,company,loggedby
       ,attention,'Received',today,datedue,id);
END IF;

<<the_end>>
NULL;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    raise_application_error(-20999,'An error occured in' ||
        SQLCODE || '-ERROR-' || SQLERRM);
END sp_ssjm_newworkorder;
```

By all means try to avoid unconditional branching. Using `GOTO` operator is very, very not good practice. It kills readability, code like that hard to debug. It will cause you and everybody who will look at that code after you a headache. Moreover if the query

```
SELECT  client_id   --grab client_id
INTO id 
FROM    ssjm_client
WHERE ssjm_client.name=company;
```

returns no rows the exception `NO_DATA_FOUND` will be immediately raised and execution of the code halts. So `IF id IS NULL THEN` condition will never be evaluated. You may rewrite your code by removing that condition and adding `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception handler in the `EXCEPTION` section of your code. And of course as @Rob van Wijk correctly pointed out in the comment

> but code can be cleaned up further. today variable can be removed and
>   the WHEN OTHERS should definitely be removed. As it is now, it just
>   transforms an error to a longer error message without more detail and
>   most importantly: it disguises the line number where the real error
>   took place.

there is no need of `today` variable, `SYSDATE` can be used directly in the `values` clause of the `insert` statement, and `WHEN OTHERS` can be removed as well.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_ssjm_newworkorder
(
workorderno IN NUMBER,
company     IN CHAR,
attention   IN CHAR,
datedue     IN DATE,
loggedby    IN CHAR
)
AS  
  id     NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT client_id   --grab client_id
    INTO id
    FROM ssjm_client
   WHERE ssjm_client.name=company;

    INSERT INTO ssjm_workorder      
      VALUES(workorderno,workorderno,company,loggedby
            ,attention,'Received',SYSDATE,datedue,id);

EXCEPTION
    when NO_DATA_FOUND
    then dbms_output.put_line('Please create client first');
END sp_ssjm_newworkorder;
```

Comment: Good answer (+1), but code can be cleaned up further. today variable can be removed and the WHEN OTHERS should definitely be removed. As it is now, it just transforms an error to a longer error message without more detail and most importantly: it disguises the line number where the real error took place.

Comment: Could you be kind enough to explain why there is no need for WHEN OTHERS exception. Regards

Comment: @Polppan When exception other than `NO_DATA_FOUND` is raised  error message will give us a line number where `raise_application_error` function has been called and not the line of the statement that hit the exception. So if we would have several `insert` statements and one of them raised `unique constraint violated` exception we would not know which one. But we can keep `WHEN OTHERS` and use `SQLERRM` combined with `DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE` function(10g onward) to get the error message and the line where exception took place in order to log the error.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov So `WHEN_OTHERS` is required with the combination of `SQLERRM`?

Comment: @Polppan It would be useful to log an error and then propagate an exception.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I was wondering with this statement in your comment.  `But we can keep WHEN OTHERS and use SQLERRM combined with DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE function`

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Thank you very much, very clear answer. Very appreciated. That is actually my first PL/SQL program, learned a lot from it, i will try to avoid the GOTO statement from now on.

Comment: @Polppan I thought I already explained it. To see it for yourself, please run "begin if 1/0 then null; end if; end;" and "begin if 1/0 then null; end if; exception when others then raise_application_error(-20000,sqlcode || ' ERROR ' || sqlerrm); end;", put them on multiple lines and run them. Which error stack do you like most? (hint: it's the first)